# how to read the file which is in application itself and how to add in setup?

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I have a class library which reads the XML file.
I am using VS 2012 and VB.NET language.

I am getting confused about how to read the file which is in folder of a application itself.

Right now I have given the path as

```
Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("C:\mailpara.xml")
```

but its hard-coded , but I want to make a folder in app. and want to read from that 
folder itself.

I want to know how to read the file from the folder of a application.
How to read the file after installation on client's machine and how to add the file while making the set up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like;

```
Dim directory as String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(directory & "\MyFolderName\mailpara.xml")
```

Comment: No, it looking in bin folder...I want to read from the other folder.

Comment: The "\MyFolderName" I added refers to your other folder. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yeah, when you are running in Visual Studio, this will be your apps folder. However, when you install your app on your clients machine, the `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` will refer to the local install location instead ;-)

Comment: also want to know how to add file while creating setup ? and how to read after setup in installed  ?

Comment: Depending on which Setup Project you use, you can include a given file relatively easily. For instance, for a Visual Studio Setup Project... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353#

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application.StartupPath property to retrieve the startup path of the application.

```
Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(Application.StartupPath & "mailpara.xml")
```

You might want to add a check to ensure that the path ends with a `\` (I think it may or may not be present depending on whether the path is a root folder or not).

Comment: No, it looking in bin folder...I want to read from the other folder.

Comment: The \bin folder is only used by Visual Studio; once deployed, the startup path will be the one where you put your .exe file (e.g. `C:\Program Files\MyCompanyName\MyApplication\ `)